# How can I change the value of a state variable in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have two tables, "Member" and "Address" which are related. My form has fields to both tables and I want my application to return the id of the member and use it in the foreign key of the address, however when I try to change the value of id_member with the response of the post function, it doesn't change and it remains without value.

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { FiArrowLeft } from 'react-icons/fi';

    import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    import { Form, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

    import api from '../../services/api';

    import './styles.css';

    export default function NewMember() {
        const [name, setName] = useState('');
        const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
        const [situation, setSituation] = useState('');
        const [birth, setBirth] = useState('');
        const [rg, setRg] = useState('');
        const [street, setStreet] = useState('');
        const [number, setNumber] = useState('');
        const [neighborhood, setNeighborhood] = useState('');
        const [city, setCity] = useState('');
        const [uf, setUf] = useState('');
        const [zip, setZip] = useState('');
        const [id_member, setId_member] = useState(0);


        const history = useHistory();

        const userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');

        async function handleNewMember(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const dataMember = {
                name,
                email,
                situation,
                birth,
                rg,
            };
            const dataAddress = {
                street,
                number,
                neighborhood,
                city,
                uf,
                zip,
                id_member,
            };
            try {
                const response = await api.post('members', dataMember, {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: userId,
                    }
                })
                

                setId_member(response.data.id);
                await api.post('/address', dataAddress);
                history.push('/profile');
            } catch (err) {
                alert('Erro ao cadastrar integrante, tente novamente.')
            }


        }
        return (
            <div className="new-member-container">
                <div className="content">
                    <Form onSubmit={handleNewMember}>
                        <Form.Row className="space">
                            <Col xs={7}>
                                <Form.Label>Nome</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="João Alves da Silva"
                                    value={name}
                                    onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
                                />
                            </Col>
                            <Col>
                                <Form.Label>E-mail</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="email"
                                    placeholder="e-mail@gmail.com"
                                    value={email}
                                    onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                                />
                            </Col>
                        </Form.Row>
                        <Form.Row className="space">
                            <Col xs={6}>
                                <Form.Label>Nascimento</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="date"
                                    placeholder="24/01/2000"
                                    value={birth}
                                    onChange={e => setBirth(e.target.value)}
                                />
                            </Col>
                            <Col>
                                <Form.Label>RG</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    placeholder="50.149.996-9"
                                    value={rg}
                                    onChange={e => setRg(e.target.value)}
                                />
                            </Col>
                        </Form.Row >
                        <Form.Row className="space">
                            <Col xs={6}>
                                <Form.Label>Rua</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    placeholder="Rua Loefgren"
                                    value={street}
                                    onChange={e => setStreet(e.target.value)}
                                />
                            </Col>
                            <Col>
                                <Form.Label>Número</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    placeholder="2109"
                                    value={number}
                                    onChange={e => setNumber(e.target.value)}
                                />
                            </Col>
                            <Col xs={4}>
                                <Form.Label>Bairro</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    placeholder="Vila Clementino"
                                    value={neighborhood}
                                    onChange={e => setNeighborhood(e.target.value)}
                                />
                            </Col>
                        </Form.Row >
                        <Form.Row className="space">
                            <Col xs={4}>
                                <Form.Label>City</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    placeholder="São Paulo"
                                    value={city}
                                    onChange={e => setCity(e.target.value)}
                                />
                            </Col>
                            <Col xs={2}>
                                <Form.Label>UF</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    placeholder="SP"
                                    value={uf}
                                    onChange={e => setUf(e.target.value)}
                                />
                            </Col>
                            <Col xs={2}>
                                <Form.Label>CEP</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    placeholder="04040-030"
                                    value={zip}
                                    onChange={e => setZip(e.target.value)}
                                />
                            </Col>
                            <Col>
                                <Form.Label>Situação</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    value={situation}
                                    placeholder="Ativo"
                                    onChange={e => setSituation(e.target.value)}>
                                </Form.Control>
                            </Col>

                        </Form.Row>
                        <button className="button" type="submit">
                            Cadastrar
                        </button>

                        <Link className="back-link" to="/profile">
                            <FiArrowLeft size={16} color="#01A8E5" />
                            Voltar para Home
                        </Link>
                    </Form>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

My Controller:

```
const connection = require('../database/connection');
module.exports = {
    async index(request, response) {
        const { page = 1 } = request.query;

        const [count] = await connection('member').count();

        const members = await connection('member')
            .join('address', 'id_member', '=', 'member.id')
            .limit(30)
            .offset((page - 1) * 30)
            .select([
                'member.*',
                'address.street',
                'address.number',
                'address.neighborhood',
                'address.city',
                'address.uf',
                'address.zip']);

        response.header('X-Total-Count', count['count(*)']);

        return response.json(members);
    },

    async create(request, response) {
        const { name, email, situation, birth, rg } = request.body;

        const [id] = await connection('member').insert({
            name,
            email,
            situation,
            birth,
            rg,
        });

        return response.json({ id });
    },
    async delete(request, response) {
        const { id } = request.params;

        const members = await connection('member')
            .where('id', id)
            .select('id')
            .first();

        if (!members) {
            return response.status(404).json({ error: 'Operation Not Found.' });
        }
        else {
            await connection('member').where('id', id).delete();

            return response.status(204).send();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you post the code for <Form.Control/>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async function handleNewMember(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const dataMember = {
            name,
            email,
            situation,
            birth,
            rg,
        };
        const dataAddress = {
            street,
            number,
            neighborhood,
            city,
            uf,
            zip
        };
        try {
            const response = await api.post('members', dataMember, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: userId,
                }
            })
            const id_member = response.data.id
            setId_member(id_member);
            // `setId_member` or setXxx is async. so use the `id_member` directly. or you will always get it's previous value
            dataAddress.id_member = id_member
            await api.post('/address', dataAddress);
            history.push('/profile');
        } catch (err) {
            alert('Erro ao cadastrar integrante, tente novamente.')
        }
    }
```

Comment: it's fine. have a nice day ;)